# Passing data via props and using array.map not working

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I'm currently building app and am using the firebase for data storage, and am having an issue spreading the same data to the two different components( for example: AllProjects and SelectedProject) once the user is logged in.

In the first component(AllProjects), it works and am able to map through the data array and build cards that I want to use for navigating to the second component(SelectedProject). But when I map the same data array again, to spread its content to SelectedProject component(to each individual project), the map is not working and only the data from the first project in the array is being passed to each other project.

```
function UserPanel(props) {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  //get data from firebase
  useEffect(() => {
    return db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(`${props.user.uid}`)
      .collection("projects")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const docs = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          docs.push({
            ...doc.data()
          });
        });
        setProjects(docs);
      });
  }, [props.user.uid]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav user={props.user} />
      <Router>
        <AllProjects projects={projects} path="/" />

          {projects.map(project => (
          <SelectedProject
            project={project}
            path="projects/:projectId"
            key={project.id}
          />
        ))}

      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserPanel;
```

First Component

```
function AllProjects(props) {
  return  (
    <div>
      {props.projects.map(projects=> (
        <Link key={projects.id} to={`/projects/${projects.id}`}>
          <ProjectCard projects={projects} />
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the solution for spreading all data dynamically through the app(even not sure now if it's possible?) but rather making a second API call from inside the second component and using id from the router path to select the desired project.